# Prove that function is totally computable

Tags: computability

The problem that I'm working on is

> Graph of function $f : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is set {$(x, f(x))$, $x \in  \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x)$ $\neq \perp$} $\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{2}$. Prove that function $f$ is totally computable when $f(x)$ is defined for every $x $ $\in $  $\mathbb{N}$ and his graph is recursively enumerable set.

Do you have any suggestions how to prove it?
I have recently started learning theory of computability so some easy to understand answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a computable enumeration of the graph of the function. On input $n$, wait for a pair $(n,y)$ to appear in the graph. When you find such a pair, output $y$. This is a computable procedure that computes $f$.

The totality of the function is irrelevant to this argument. What the procedure shows is that a function $f$ is computable if and only if the graph of $f$ is computably enumerable.

But if you also know (by your hypothesis) that the function is total, then you've got a total computable function.